# Restart node js process in the process

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, process

I'm looking for a way to restart my node js web app from inside the app.
The goal is to restart the web app for changes to take effect (CRON settings).

Basically i have a button on the web interface that request a restart on the server. I don't want the server to detect a change automatically. I looking for a way to trigger a restart of the web app on the server through a client request.

I can't make my mind which is the best way to do that (forever, python file, ...).

If someone has already do that, it will be great to share your solution :)

Thanks.

Comment: please clearify in detaile what do you want to ask ??

Comment: So you want your app to restart when it detects changes? Sounds more like a debug server to me. You definitely **dont** want a production server to restart if someone accidentally touches a config file.

Comment: No, not in that way.

Basically i have a button on the web interface that request a restart on the server.
I don't want the server to detect  a change automatically.

I looking for a way to trigger a restart of the web app on the server through a client request.